# Using Bing search API returns different results than the site

Tags: bing

Why is it that when using the Bing search API results come back far different than what we tried on the Bing.com search page?

In testing, I get great results if I search for an exact phrase, but sending that same request through the API and it comes back with different results.

Is there a way to use the Bing API that it will return the same results as a normal web search?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the results would eventually be consistent. Many search engines actually balance requests across many server-farms and each server might give subtly different answers to any other. Partly this is just load balancing, but it is also by design as it reduces predictability of search position.

As pages "settle" into a ranking, the results will become more similar even from different servers, but when a site is moving and shaking, you are more likely to see a range of different results - sometimes even by repeating the search twice in your browser. You are more likely to see the difference when comparing the results from your browser to the results from an API call.